# Laravel 4 - Understanding models

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help me out understanding models a bit more

I have 2 tables - users, conversation_replys

I need to run the following SQL

```
<?php
$query= mysql_query("SELECT R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply,U.user_id,U.username,U.email FROM users U, conversation_reply R WHERE R.user_id_fk=U.user_id and R.c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY R.cr_id ASC LIMIT 20") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    //HTML Output
}
?>
```

How would i turn that into laravels ORM language and as its referencing 2 tables, what model should i put it in ( users or conversation_reply ) ..

Is there any chance someone could hook me up with a little code to show me how i would get all this info to display?

Im totally lost haha

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your conversations Model

```
<?php

class Conversation extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'conversation_reply';
}
```

Define your User model and a relation between the user and the conversations table

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function conversations
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Conversation', 'user_id_fk');
    }
}
```

Then Laravel will let you do this:

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach($user->conversations as $conversation)
{
    echo $conversation->text;
}
```

Comment: So just doing that will be equivalent to the SQL in my example?

Comment: Not exactly, but 95% of it. Order By would be something like `$user->conversations()->orderBy('id')->get();`, i.e.

Comment: Oh ok, and what about the conversation data R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply thats in the query?

Comment: When you deal with models, all your attributes are passed in the queries, unless you specify that you need just some of them: `$user->conversations()->orderBy('id')->get('cr_id');`

Comment: Wow, thats amazingly easy, but going to take some time to get used to ... So using the code you gave, i could just do echo $conversation->time' and it will show the time from the conversation_reply table

Comment: It should, yeah, but my code might not be perfecly fit to yours, do some check on it. And now that you understand it better, take a look at this part of the docs: http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships.

Comment: Thank you so much ... You dont happen to freelance would you?